# I am getting an error after trying to upgrade my pip

Tags: python

I tried to run:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

and when I did I got this error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 311, in run
    root=options.root_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 640, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 716, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 125, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 315, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 300, in move
    rmtree(src)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 247, in rmtree
    rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 252, in rmtree
    onerror(os.remove, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 250, in rmtree
    os.remove(fullname)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/dependency_links.txt'
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: add `sudo` if you are allowed :)

Comment: @xsquared make your answer so I am able to give you credit for it. That's what the issue was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pip upgrade needs root authorization because it accesses system paths.
So add `sudo` in front of your command.

Hint: As far as I know `Permission denied` always means: requiring root privileges.

Comment: I also have to use sudo when installing django for some reason now. I didnt have to do that before

Comment: If you install packages with pip, you can pass the `--user` flag, which will cause pip to install the package at a location in your home folder and you won't need root permission.